# Why is there no charge in NH3

Tags: bond

The formation of $NH_3$ is by covalent bond,i.e sharing of electrons take place. Here $N$ now has 8 electrons in it's outermost shell,$3$ more than it's original state,so it should have charge $-3$. Furthermore each hydrogen has $2$ electrons in it's outermost shell,$1$ more than usual,so total charge on hydrogen should be $3\times(-1)$. So the net charge on $NH_3$ should be $-6$. Then why is it neutral?

Comment: How many valence electrons are there in ammonia? Is it *really* 8 + 2 + 2 + 2?

Comment: You have counted each of the 6 electrons from 3 bonds twice.

Comment: Sorry but I didn't understand,since this is a covalent bond,electrons are shared,so $N$ has now the electrons of $H$ and $H$ has the electrons of $N$,going by not nitrogen has obtained $3$ more electrons from the hydrogens and each hydrogen has obtained one more electron on $N$,that's how I actually considered the charges.

Comment: @TanjiroO Each shared electron must be counted as just a half of an electron. Similarly as in crystallography cells, an atom shared with N cells is counted as 1/N atoms. So nitrogen atom in NH3 has 4 + 6/2=7 electrons, hydrogen atoms 2/2=1 electron. How simple, dear Dr. Watson!

Answer (score 1):

Let's actually **count** protons and electrons.

Nitrogen has  7 protons and each hydrogen has 1 proton which makes a total of 10 protons.

Nitrogen has 10  electrons out of the  3 that are shared with the hydrogen atoms.

Each Hydrogen has 2 electrons out of the 1 is shared with the nitrogen atom.

We get a total of 10 protons and 10 electrons.But why 10 electrons?Because 3 electrons are in both sets of nitrogen and electron protons.

[image]

Comment: Instead of counting the total number of protons and electrons,shouldn't we be counting respective charges?Like nitrogen has $7$ protons and $10$ electrons now,so it has a charge of $-3$ and so on

Comment: Study set theory I recommend this video:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yCwnifwVjIg

Comment: I actually know about set theory,what is the $C$ that you mentioned? Also why aren't we considering charges on respective atoms? The thing you did is you derived 10 electrons and 10 protons,but I am talking about comparing proton number of an atom and the excess of electron that atom gets.

Comment: Which means I am dealing with things individually

Comment: C is the # of electrons